# No SuchBucket error when trying to upload file to digital ocean .NET

Tags: c#, digital-ocean

im having problem with uploading file to digitalocean.

```
private static readonly AmazonS3Config s3ClientConfig = new AmazonS3Config
               {
                   ServiceURL = digOceanEndPoint
       };
private static async Task DO_UploadFileAsync()
        {
            //Test DigitalOcean Upload
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

                IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, s3ClientConfig);
                
                var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
                var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "valentindb",
                    FilePath = "C:\\Temp\\HelpDesk.jpg",
                    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
                    PartSize = 6291456, // 6 MB
                    Key = "HelpDesk.jpg",
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                };
                await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);

            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                errorMessage = e.Message;
                Console.WriteLine("AWS Error encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorMessage = e.Message;
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is code im trying to use. When i enter UploadAsync function, exception is being throw with status of:
"Error making request with Error Code NoSuchBucket and Http Status Code NotFound. No further error information was returned by the service."

Does anyone know whats wrong and what should i check?

Comment: The name of the bucket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

BucketName = "valentindb",
should be => "valentindb.yourRegion.digitaloceanspaces.com"

I don't understand why, but now upload works.

Comment: I got the error `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`. When I set bucketname from `mybucket` to `mybucket.yourRegion.digitaloceanspaces.com` is working. I also no idea why